# Availability of SagePay responsive templates

Tags: opayo

I am integrating SagePay into our responsive designed shopping cart via iframe using the 'LOW' profile. Whilst it looks ok on a desktop, when scaled down to mobile size it starts to look bad. I have only come across one website that has made an attempt at making the SagePay inframe form responsive and provided the edited templates for free:

http://www.bluelinemedia.co.uk/mobile-sagepay-pages

It works insofar as the width of the form fields behave better but it could perform even better. I was wondering if anyone has access to different responsive SagePay templates, paid for or free? Ideally I would want desktops to show a wider credit card details form that then stacks the fields and labels when it goes into mobile territory. I would have thought that, as we are in 2014 and mobile devices more inmportant than ever, the development kit might include some responsive templates...sadly not. Does anyone know when SagePay are going to offer these in their kits?

Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 1):

Sage Pay are looking into the development of mobile optimised payment pages early next year, 2015. More information to follow thereafter.